# hide option select value based on option value selected on first options

Tags: php, javascript

I have two select option field.

```
<div style="float:left; width:7%">
<label>Type</label>             
<select name="ostatus" id="ostatus" class="input-small">
<option value="Actual">Actual</option>
<option value="Ghost">Ghost</option>
</select>


<div style="float:left; width:7%">
<label>Upgrade</label>              
<select name="oupg" id="oupg" class="input-small">
<option value="Exp" >Exp</option>
<option value="Post" >Post</option>
<option value="Upgrade" >Upg</option>
<option value="Retail" >Retail</option>
<option value="Prepaid" >Prepaid</option>
</select>
```

If on the Type select, Ghost is selected, I would like to hide option Retail and Prepaid under the upgrade options. How do I go about this? I am able to hide the whole div container for upgrade but I only want to hide those last two options. Please some assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ostatus').on('change',function() {
        if($(this).val()== 'Ghost'){
          $('#oupg') .find ("option[value=Retail]").hide();
           $('#oupg') .find ("option[value=Prepaid]").hide();
        }
        else{
            $('#oupg') .find ("option[value=Retail]").show();
           $('#oupg') .find ("option[value=Prepaid]").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much I went with this option as I am trying to learn jquery and I actually understood this one =)

Answer (score 2):

Using Javascript and `display:none` css styling you can accomplish this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideOpt() {
            var type = document.getElementById("ostatus");
            var upgrade = document.getElementById("oupg");
            if (type.options[type.selectedIndex].value == 'Ghost') {
                upgrade.options[3].style.display = 'none';
                upgrade.options[4].style.display = 'none';
                // IE exception
                upgrade.options[3].disabled = true;
                upgrade.options[4].disabled = true;
            } else {
                upgrade.options[3].style.display = 'block';
                upgrade.options[4].style.display = 'block';
                // IE exception
                upgrade.options[3].disabled = false;
                upgrade.options[4].disabled = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<label>Type</label>             
<select name="ostatus" id="ostatus" onchange="return hideOpt();" class="input-small">
    <option value="Actual">Actual</option>
    <option value="Ghost">Ghost</option>
</select>


<label>Upgrade</label>              
<select name="oupg" id="oupg" class="input-small">
    <option value="Exp" >Exp</option>
    <option value="Post" >Post</option>
    <option value="Upgrade" >Upg</option>
    <option value="Retail" >Retail</option>
    <option value="Prepaid" >Prepaid</option>
</select>
```

---

**Edit:**

Added `else` statement to show the options again when 'Actual' is selected.

Comment: thank you very much i actually understood your code (im learning) but I went with the jquery option posted by Reshil

Comment: Not a problem, there are a couple different ways to accomplish what you set out for. Always good to learn and use something new. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide `option` elements in all browsers, but you can disable them:

```
document.querySelector("#oupg option[value=Retail]").disabled = true;
document.querySelector("#oupg option[value=Prepaid]").disabled = true;
```

This will work in IE8 and up.

---

If you want IE7 and lower support, then:

```
var opts = document.getElementById("oupg").options;

opts[opts.length - 2].disabled = true;
opts[opts.length - 1].disabled = true;
```