# Hide select value if date value is specific with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="product-field product-field-type-D">
    <span class="product-fields-title-wrapper">
         <span class="product-fields-title"><strong>Delivery date</strong></span>
    </span>
    <span class="product-field-display">
    <span class="product_custom_date">
    <input class="datepicker-db" id="customProductData.140.7." type="hidden" name="customProductData[140][7]" value="">
    <input id="customProductData.140.7._text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="text" value="-Ποτέ-">
    <span class="vmicon vmicon-16-logout icon-nofloat js-date-reset"></span></span></span>
</div>

<div class="product-field product-field-type-S">
    <span class="product-fields-title-wrapper">
    <span class="product-fields-title"><strong>Delivery hour</strong></span>
    </span>
    <span class="product-field-display">
    <select id="customProductData_140_662" name="customProductData[140][8][662]" class="vm-chzn-select chzn-done" style="display: none;">
    <option value="08.00-08.30">08.00-08.30</option>
    <option value="08.30-09.00">08.30-09.00</option>
    <option value="09.00-09.30">09.00-09.30</option>
    <option value="09.30-10.00">09.30-10.00</option>
    <option value="10.00-10.30">10.00-10.30</option>
    <option value="10.30-11.00">10.30-11.00</option>
    <option value="11.00-11.30">11.00-11.30</option>
    <option value="11.30-12.00">11.30-12.00</option>
    <option value="12.00-12.30">12.00-12.30</option>
    <option value="12.30-13.00">12.30-13.00</option>
    </select>
    <div id="customProductData_140_662_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 200px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>08.00-08.30</span><div><b></b></div></a>
    <div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 198px; top: 25px;">
    <div class="chzn-search">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" style="width: 163px;">
    </div>
    <ul class="chzn-results">
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">08.00-08.30</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">08.30-09.00</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">09.00-09.30</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">09.30-10.00</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">10.00-10.30</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">10.30-11.00</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_6" class="active-result" style="">11.00-11.30</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_7" class="active-result" style="">11.30-12.00</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_8" class="active-result" style="">12.00-12.30</li>
    <li id="customProductData_140_662_chzn_o_9" class="inactive-result active-result" style="">12.30-13.00</li></ul></div></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

and i want if date from Delivery date field is equal to specific date, then to hide the last value from Delivery hour field (12.30-13.00). Is this possible with jquery?

I tried to follow example from here: [hide option select value based on option value selected on first options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596563/hide-option-select-value-based-on-option-value-selected-on-first-options) but with no results

EDIT: From my few personal experience i tried this with no results:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.datepicker-db').on('change',function() {
            if($(this).val()== '30.04.2016'){
              $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').hide();
            }
            else{
                $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').show();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Notice that i cannot use IDs of items but only classes because IDs are generated dynamically and not the same every time

Comment: Sorry! Your code is not readable or not complete

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It makes it much easier for others to read and help you with.

Comment: please add the script code .. whatever you have tried so far ? Thnx

Comment: I tried this: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker-db').on('change',function() {
        if($(this).val()== '30.04.2016'){
          $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').hide();
        }
        else{
            $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').show();
        }
    });
});
</script> with no results

Comment: Are you using jquery datepicker?

Comment: Please see http://agorainfolive4.eu/bonjour/index.php/family-breakfast to check. Below price there is a datepicker field and below the Delivery hour from where i need to hide value depending on datepicker field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help you. I checked this code in your website (this link you provided earlier). this piece of code little bit of hack to achieve your requirement.

```
        function getElement(bHide){
        var timeStr = "12.30-13.00";
        var ele = jQuery('.vm-chzn-select option[value="'+timeStr+'"]').closest("select").siblings("div.chzn-container").find("ul>li");
        for(var index=0;index<ele.length;index++){
            if(jQuery(ele[index]).html() == timeStr)
            {
                if(bHide)
                    jQuery(ele[index]).hide();
                else
                    jQuery(ele[index]).show();
            }
        }
    }

    jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker().data("datepicker").settings["onSelect"] = function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == '30/04/2016') 
        {
            getElement(true);
        } else {
            getElement(false);
        }
    }
```

Actually in above code, I wrote a function to identify the element which you want to hide because the drop down you are using is a ul-li element instead of select.

So have look and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

your script is correct
It works for me but only in a Case that is you need to change your input type from `hidden` to `text` like below:

```
<input class="datepicker-db" id="customProductData.140.7." type="hidden" name="customProductData[140][7]" value="">
```

change to

```
<input class="datepicker-db" id="customProductData.140.7." type="text" name="customProductData[140][7]" value="">
```

hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your requirement:

```
if(condition for specific date) {
    $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your event. Actually you are binding the change event to a hidden input. So it will never fire.

You should perform the action on selecting the date. If you are using jQuery datepicker then use the below code and check you condition and hide the element.

```
$("#customProductData.140.7._text").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
         if($(this).val() == '30.04.2016')
         {
              $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').hide();
         } else{ 
              $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').show();
         }
    }
});
```

May be this help you. Please let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Actually i don't know why you are using hidden field to store the date. Remove that one and use the above code.

Comment: This is on Joomla and Virtuemart. As i saw now it uses 2 inputs, one hidden and one below for styling but as i see the hidden one takes the date. I tried using at your code also the id: customProductData.140.7. with class datepicker-db which is from 1st input (hidden) and also the second input which is visible and also with value 2016-04-30 which is the normal value that hidden input takes. Also i tried to change hidden to text and still no results at all. I made all testings on browser through inspection

Comment: As i already told you that when you are selecting the date it is actually not performing action on your hidden field. Thats why your code is not working. Otherwise there nothing wrong in your code. Tell me one thing, Are you initializing(write any code to display) the date-picker or it is doing by your CMS.

Comment: I don't do anything. Its all from my CMS! Should i include any part of coding that calls something?If yes please give me the code because i don't understand how its working. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes please. Try the above code, this should work. Please let me know, if you still face any issue.

Comment: Which above code? The one that is the the post above those comments? I try this with no results at all...

Comment: Try this one: $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
         if($(this).val() == '30.04.2016')
         {
              $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').hide();
         } else{ 
              $('.vm-chzn-select option[value="12.30-13.00"]').show();
         }
    }
});

Comment: Give me sometime, i will update the solution for this.

Comment: Again nothing! Notice from the link: agorainfolive4.eu/bonjour/index.php/family-breakfast that when you choose the date the value is this: 2016-04-30. I tried also with this value but no success at all!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the following is working:

but i need to show/hide by value and not by last child. Any help?

```
jQuery(".datepicker").change(function() {
     var val = jQuery(this).datepicker().val();
     console.log(val);
      if (val == '30.04.2016') {
       console.log("hide");
        jQuery(".chzn-drop li:last-child ").hide();
     } else {
       console.log("show");
         jQuery(".chzn-drop li:last-child ").show();
     }
    });
```